# Double negation (!!) in JavaScript - what is the purpose?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)

I have encountered this piece of code:

```
function printStackTrace(options) {
    options = options || {guess: true};
    var ex = options.e || null, guess = !!options.guess;
    var p = new printStackTrace.implementation(), result = p.run(ex);
    return (guess) ? p.guessAnonymousFunctions(result) : result;
}
```

And I couldn't help to wonder why the double negation? And is there an alternative way to achieve the same effect?

(The code is from https://github.com/eriwen/javascript-stacktrace/blob/master/stacktrace.js.)

Answer (score 276, accepted):

It casts to boolean. The first `!` negates it once, converting values like so:

- `undefined` to `true`
- `null` to `true`
- `+0` to `true`
- `-0` to `true`
- `''` to `true`
- `NaN` to `true`
- `false` to `true`
- All other expressions to `false`

Then the other `!` negates it again. A concise cast to boolean, exactly equivalent to [ToBoolean](https://es5.github.io/#x9.2) simply because `!` is [defined as its negation](https://es5.github.io/#x11.4.9). It’s unnecessary here, though, because it’s only used as the condition of the conditional operator, which will determine truthiness in the same way.

Comment: @pimvdb I'm curious why you added the answer to add `+0` and `-0`. There is no such thing `-\+0` as 0 is... 0...

Comment: @gdoron: `1 / 0 === Infinity`; `1 / -0 === -Infinity`

Comment: `if(guess)` is the same as `if(!!guess)`?
For JS, what case would you need to do this for other than display purposes (showing that a variable is true or false)?  It seems like an unneeded step, if you're only using it within a conditional expression or an IF statement, since the object's truthiness will always be evaluated. Is that accurate?

Comment: @JoePC: Yes, you’re correct in saying that it’s an unneeded step *if you’re only using it within a conditional expression or an if statement*.

Comment: @Ry- Thank you!  I came across a good case for it after I posted that.  When doing a return from a function and needing a boolean type to be returned and not the object itself, such as: `return !!guess;`  I can see why the earlier usage is not totally necessary. (`guess = !!option.guess`)

Comment: I think this answer would be improved by including the above comments about when it is useful and when it isn't.

Comment: @JoePC it's useful when short circuiting in React :) https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator

Answer (score 70):

```
var x = "somevalue"
var isNotEmpty = !!x.length;
```

Let's break it to pieces:

```
x.length   // 9
!x.length  // false
!!x.length // true
```

So it's used to convert a "truethy" "falsy" value to a Boolean.

---

The following values are equivalent to false in **conditional statements**:

- false
- null
- undefined
- The empty string `""` (\ `''`)
- The number 0
- The number NaN

*All* other values are equivalent to true.

Answer (score 33):

Double-negation turns a "truthy" or "falsy" value into a Boolean value, `true` or `false`.

Most are familiar with using truthiness as a test:

```
if (options.guess) {
    // Runs if 'options.guess' is truthy,
}
```

But that does not necessarily mean:

```
options.guess === true   // Could be, could be not
```

If you need to force a "truthy" value to a true boolean value, `!!` is a convenient way to do that:

```
!!options.guess === true   // Always true if 'options.guess' is truthy
```

Comment: This answer made it clear. I had this same doubt between truthy and boolean value