# Logical operator && and two strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, operators

When I use the logical operator && between two strings, why does it give me the second string as output:

```js
console.log("" && "Dog");    // ""
console.log("Cat" && "Dog"); // "Dog"
```

I realize that the with the exception of `0`, `false`, `null`, `undefined`, `""` and `NaN`, everything else is evaluated as a boolean true in a logical expression like the one above. But why is the output the second string and not the first? And why is the ouput not just "true" since it is being evaluated as a boolean expression?

Comment: Because that's how JS works, and truthiness extends beyond booleans as you point out.

Comment: See this concise answer: [In the simplest terms](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32158899)

Comment: See this answer [In the simplest terms](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32158899)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

in the expression

```
"Cat" && "Dog"
// => "Dog"
```

Because you're using `&&`, JavaScript is promising you that it will verify that both sides of the expression are `true`. In this case, `"Dog"` is the just the last evaluated thing.

To be more explicit, you could do something like

```
var c = "Cat" != null && "Dog" != null
```

It's a little bit more wordy, but this boils down to

```
var c = true && true
console.log(c)
// => true
```

If you want a simple shortcut for the boolean, use the `Boolean` constructor -

```
var c = Boolean("Cat" && "Dog")
console.log(c)
// => true
```

If you just use a simple REPL or JavaScript console, you'd be able to see this output very easily.

---

Per one of the comments below

Using `||`, JavaScript is promising you that at least *one* of the sides is `true`. Since "Cat" is true, it stops there and returns "Cat". This is known as [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: "Dog" is the last evaluated thing? What about "Cat" || "Dog" (=> "Cat") then?

Comment: @su, I added a section to my answer that addresses your question :)

Comment: @user633183 explained that "Cat" || "Dog" returns "Cat" without even looking beyond the || operator. I'm wondering though, does the string "Dog" even ever get created? I'm not sure how one would check for this.

Comment: Alex, `“Dog”` will not be evaluated

Comment: then why the answer of console.log("foo" && 010) is 8?

Comment: because 010 == 8

Answer (score 17):

I think this is because of nature of logical operator &&. Javascript executes expression `"cat" && "Dog"` in following way:

Checks the value "cat" - it returns something else than "", 0, null, undefined or false and is truthy. Javascript sees `&&` and so it continues expression and faces string "Dog", which is something else than "", 0, null, undefined or false and is truthy, expression ends and expression returns the last value it checked.

If you replace `&&` with `||` expressions ends at first truthy value and thats way

```
var boolean = "cat" || "dog"
```

returns first value: `cat`

Comment: +1 Yeah, it really comes down to logic operators 101, doesn't it? :) Nice write up.

Answer (score 14):

Answer by @naomik pretty much covers it. If you want to go deep, I suggest taking a look at the ECMAScript specification, section 11.11:

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.11

In the "Semantics" section, we can see:

> The production *LogicalANDExpression* : *LogicalANDExpression* &&
>   *BitwiseORExpression* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *lref* be the result of evaluating *LogicalANDExpression*.
> 2. Let *lval* be GetValue(*lref*).
> 3. If ToBoolean(*lval*) is false, return *lval*.
> 4. Let *rref* be the result of evaluating *BitwiseORExpression*.
> 5. Return GetValue(*rref*).

Comment: This question is 3 years old, why post another answer?

Comment: Because I just found it, and thought I had a little extra knowledge to share that wasn't shared previously ;) I don't think questions have "expiration date" on SO :)

Comment: Hi, what are the full forms of lref, lval, rref, rval

Comment: @firstpostcommenter They are defined in the quote: lref is the result of evaluating LogicalANDExpression (i.e. the left hand term), lval is the result of GetValue(lref), and so on. For a definition of GetValue, I suggest taking a look in the linked documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way logic works, if you need to test if both items are true, and you already know the first item is true, then the test totally depends on the second item.

true && someValue is equivalent to just someValue

For this reason, the operator && can be handled by returning its operands instead of true/false values, and just testing the first operand and not the second

a && b:

- if a evaluates to false, no need to test further, return a (as it's false)
- else if a evaluates to true, the result totally depends on b, so just return b (no need to test if b evaluates to true or false, just return it)

In code this is like

```
function and(a,b) {
    if(!a) return a;
    return b;
}
```

Similarly operator || can be defined as

```
function or(a,b) {
    if(a) return a;
    return b;
}
```

Returning operands instead of true/false has a few advantages:

- requires less evaluations (notice b is never evaluated, in both cases)
- does not require a definition of true/false so it works more broadly, even cross language or if the value of "true" changes
- can be "hacked" to be used, without an if, to do stuff like string1 && string2 that has a useful meaning: "if string1 is not empty use string2 otherwise keep it empty (to replace every word of a string with the text "word": `aString.split(" ").map(function(word) {return word && "word"});`

JavaScripters love that kind of stuff (exploiting one operator side effect out of the usual context to get a different, unexpected behaviour), they do this to show off language knowlodge at parties. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can do it much simpler:

To verify that a string is empty, you can use the ! operator also in javascript.

```
let a = '';
console.log(!a);  // => true

a = 'foo';
console.log(!a)   // => false
```

If you use this operator again, now you are negating a boolean instead of a string. In your case:

```
console.log(!!'' && !!'Dog');    // => false
console.log(!!'Cat' && !!'Dog'); // => true
```

you can also look at this article: [Double negation (!!) in JavaScript - what is the purpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467475/double-negation-in-javascript-what-is-the-purpose)