# Javascript how to use the and/or operator with parenthesis

Tags: javascript, operators, or-operator

I have an object that contains a string `HelloWorld` in the attribute `hello`. I want to check for two strings, and if it does not match with either one, then I want to execute certain code.

```
var item = { hello: "HelloWorld" }
item.hello !== "HelloWorld" && item.hello !== "GoodbyeWorld" // false, correct
```

However, I feel this can be optimized and made more readable:

```
item.hello !== ("GoodbyeWorld" && "HelloWorld") // false, correct
item.hello !== ("HelloWorld" && "GoodbyeWorld") // true   WTF?
```

I expected both checks to be falsy, but surely I'm missing something here. I think I do not have a correct understanding of the AND/OR operator in javascript, or I am using the parenthesis in a wrong manner. Can anyone explain?

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/N97Kv/2/)

Comment: You can't do it like that. I can't think of a single language that supports such a construct. For a more detailed explanation, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17200368/146205.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of `"HelloWorld" && "GoodbyeWorld"` is `"GoodbyeWorld"` which is why you're getting the result you are, the previous way you were doing it is the simplest solution

Comment: The result of "HelloWorld" && "GoodbyeWorld" is "GoodbyeWorld": thanks, that I didn't quite realize. Too bad there is no way to simplify it.

Answer (score 3):

Let's take a look at this line

`item.hello !== ("HelloWorld" && "GoodbyeWorld") // true   WTF?`

The logical [AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_.28&&.29) operator evaluates its right operand, if `lVal` is a truthy value.

*Note, a truthy value is every value which is not falsy (`null,false,0,"",undefined,NaN`)*

Since `"HelloWorld"` is indeed truthy

The expression `("HelloWorld" && "GoodbyeWorld")` evaluates to `"GoodbyeWorld"` and you're effectively comparing

`item.hello !== "GoodbyeWorld"` which can be reduced to `"HelloWorld" !== "GoodbyWorld"`

Hence, is `true`

---

However, if you're on an ES5 compatible environment you could use [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)  to simplify it.

`!~["HelloWorld","GoodbyWorld"].indexOf(item.hello) //false`

*the above returns true if `item.hello` is not contained in the array*

Answer (score 1):

```
item.hello !== "HelloWorld" && item.hello !== "GoodbyeWorld"
```

is the proper way to test whether `item.hello` is distinct from `"HelloWorld"` and `"GoodbyeWorld"`.

An expression `A && B` in JavaScript yields a result which is either `A` or `B` and it's that result, that is compared to your `item.hello`.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't optimise the expression that way. What you are doing is elliminating one of the strings, so that you are only doing one of the comparisons.

The && operator uses short circuit evaluation, which means that if the first operand is truthy, it will just return the second operand.

So, what your code is doing is to compare the hello property value to the second one of the strings, which explains the results that you get.