# Returning && expression from JS function

Tags: javascript

Here is the function I am working with. I actually found it in [React Native documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-text-input.html#content) :

```
var testFunction = function(word) {
  return word && '';
}
```

Here is how I am using this function :

```
var testWord = testFunction("Alex");
```

The final value of `testWord`, returned by `testFunction`, is `""`.

I would have expected the returned value to be either `true` or `false`, as the result of the `&&` expression. However the value is a string of value `""`.

Could someone explain the logic behind this ?

Comment: please see related topic [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17200315/logical-operator-and-two-strings-in-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17200315/logical-operator-and-two-strings-in-javascript). You can see also a clear explanation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: @morels Short-circuiting and returning of an operand instead of a boolean are rather unrelated.

Comment: `return word && '';` is a sc evaluation and in linked wiki page you can exactly read that the expected value is the one is got by OP `JavaScript`, operands: `&, |`, expected vaue: `&&, ||  Last value`

Answer (score 5):

The `&&` evaluates as the right hand side if the LHS is true, otherwise it evaluates as the LHS. It doesn't evaluate as a boolean.

```
0 && 1 // 0 because 0 is not true
1 && 0 // 0 because 1 is true
1 && 2 // 2 because 1 is true
```

Comment: Is this not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417969/why-do-logical-operators-and-return-object-and-not-boolean-result?

Comment: Many thanks, I didn't know that