# React Dynamic class toggle multiple

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, primereact

Hello I basically want to toggle multiple div from active to inactive based on id or key.

Why cant i do something like this ?

```
<div className={  (activeId === 2? 'activecolumn' :   'inactivecolumn') && 'card middlecolumn mb-10 pt-2 pb-2 pl-2'  }   id="2" onClick={toggleMiddle.bind( 2)} >
```

I had to do this

```
<div className={  (activeId === 2? 'activecolumn card middlecolumn mb-10 pt-2 pb-2 pl-2' :   'inactivecolumn card middlecolumn mb-10 pt-2 pb-2 pl-2')   }   id="2" onClick={toggleMiddle.bind( 2)} >
```

I wish this was easy to do inline it's not jquery anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify this by using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
<div 
  className={`${activeId === 2 ? 'activecolumn' : 'inactivecolumn'} card middlecolumn mb-10 pt-2 pb-2 pl-2`} 
  id="2" 
  onClick={toggleMiddle.bind(2)}
> 
  ... 
</div>
```

The 1st one is incorrect because if you notice you are doing something like `'myTruthyString' && 'another string'`. Javascript will return the last truthy value when using && operator with strings, in this case it will only return the `'another string'`.

This [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17200315/logical-operator-and-two-strings-in-javascript) might explain it a little better than I did.

Comment: This is not working.

Comment: I edited the answer, I used the ticks for the rest of your classes in the wrong place. Please try again.