# Displaying link conditionally in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Basically, I have this code in my template:

```
<tr ng-repeat="entry in tableEntries">

  <td ng-switch="entry.url == ''">
    <span ng-switch-when="false"><a href="{{entry.url}}">{{entry.school}}</a></span>
    <span ng-switch-when="true">{{entry.school}}</span>
  </td>

  ...
</tr>
```

As you can see I'm trying to display a clickable URL when `entry.url` is not empty and a plain text otherwise. It works fine, but it looks quite ugly. Is there a more elegant solution?

Another way I can think of doing it is using `ng-if`:

```
<td>
  <span ng-if="entry.url != ''"><a href="{{entry.url}}">{{entry.school}}</a></span>
  <span ng-if="entry.url == ''">{{entry.school}}</span>
</td>
```

But then I would be repeating almost the same comparison twice, which looks even worse. How would you guys approach this?

Comment: this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810278/if-else-statement-in-angularjs-templates

Comment: Use `<td ng-switch="!!entry.url">` then you can simply use `true/false`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try.

`<div ng-show="!link">hello</div>
<div ng-show="!!link"><a href="{{link}}">hello</a></div>`

But the [`ngSwitch`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch) which you are using should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Use double negation, it cast into boolean thus `!!entry.url` will return `true` if string is not empty.

```
<td ng-switch="!!entry.url">
    <span ng-switch-when="true"><a href="{{entry.url}}">{{entry.school}}</a></span>
    <span ng-switch-when="false">{{entry.school}}</span>
</td>
```

A good read [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript) and [Double negation (!!) in javascript - what is the purpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467475/double-negation-in-javascript-what-is-the-purpose)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom directive that hides the complexity:

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="entry in tableEntries">
  <td>
    <link model="entry"></link>
  </td>
  ...
</tr>
```

**JS**

```
app.directive('link', function() {
    return  {
        restrict: 'E', 
        scope: {
           model: '='
        },
        template: '<a ng-if="model.url != ''" href="{{model.url}}">{{model.school}}</a><span ng-if="model.url == ''"> {{ model.school }}</span>'

    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend having an ng-class="{'className': whenEntryURLisWhatever}" in your td, and make it change the css styles accessed, e.g:

```
td span{ /*#normal styles#*/ }
.className span{ /*#styles in the case of added classname (when it is a link)#*/
           text-decoration: underline; 
           cursor:   pointer; 
}
```

Then just change what happens on ng-click within a function defined in your javascript code.

```
$scope.yourFunction = function(url){
    if(!!url){
        window.location = YourURL;
    }
}
```

This would cut down on code repetition, as your html could now be:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="entry in tableEntries">
  <td ng-class="{'className': !!entry.url}">
    <span ng-click="yourFunction(entry.url)">{{entry.school}}</span> 
  </td>
  ...
</tr>
```

Comment: What ng-click? I have no idea what you are talking about. Do you suggest hiding unused elements in CSS? How is it any better than what I'm doing now?

Comment: not at all, in your css you can have `.className span{ text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer; }` and any other styles you want on a link. Then inside your span, have `ng-click="yourFunction()"`

Comment: I have edited the answer to try and explain this better.