# Javascript - Why use a double negation

Tags: javascript

Within an if condidition, when does it make sense to use a double negation? I found this pattern several times:

JS

```
if(!!children.length) {   ...}
```

Comment: `!!` makes a boolean out of an expression, but in `if` is useless.

Comment: Refer to this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467475/double-negation-in-javascript-what-is-the-purpose][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467475/double-negation-in-javascript-what-is-the-purpose

Comment: it never makes sense to use a boolean conversion in an IF, the IF does that for you

Answer (score 7):

It's a common method to turn a normal expression to a boolean. It doesn't really make any sense inside an `if` statement, since it evaluates the given expression as a boolean anyways, but is useful outside.

For example:

```
const isEmpty = !!children.length;
```