# Cleaner way to write this code

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which works perfectly, but I'm calling the `getItem` function twice, which seems unnecessary. How can I tidy it up?

```
if(localStorage.getItem("preferences") == null {
    //show set preferences page
} else {
    var preferences = localStorage.getItem("preferences");
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for these suggestions. As they're all pretty much the same I will accept TJs answer as it's the cleanest and makes a good point about reordering the code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the `getItem` once:

```
var preferences = localStorage.getItem("preferences");
if (preferences == null) {
    //show set preferences page
} else {
    //do stuff
}
```

And unless it's valid that `preferences` could be a falsy value other than `null`, I'd probably invert those blocks:

```
var preferences = localStorage.getItem("preferences");
if (preferences) {
    //do stuff
} else {
    //show set preferences page
}
```

Comment: Thanks TJ for this detailed answer

Answer (score 2):

hope this helps

```
let preferences = localStorage.getItem("preferences"); 

preferences ? do stuff : show set preferences page
```

Comment: Thanks Ajay, but the 'do stuff' and 'show preferences page' code blocks are too long for this notation in this instance.

Comment: hey @Brad, you can easily make a function for both, something like: `preferences ? doStuff() : setPreferencesPage()` and write that accordingly. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var preferences = localStorage.getItem("preferences");

if(preferences) { 
    //Show preference page
} else { 
    //Do something
}
```

If the value from local storage is null, you can still assign it to a var and then check against it.

Also, you can simply check the var within the if statement without comparing to null.
Take the following for instance:

```
if(!a) {
    //Will enter here if a is null, undefined, false, empty string, 0 or NaN
}
```

Further reading: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/

Answer (score 1):

```
var preferences = localStorage.getItem("preferences");
if(!!preferences){ //check if preferences is undefined or false or null
    //show set preferences page
} else {
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: @RahulDesai if variable is null or undefined or false then it will return you false either way, apart from that it also will handle isNaN situation like parseInt("a") to false. for more see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467475/double-negation-in-javascript-what-is-the-purpose

Comment: `getItem` won't ever return `NaN` though, so it's redundant.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli what if you have "function getItem(){
  return parseInt("a")
}"

Comment: Uh? It's from `localStorage`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem

Comment: ah, ok that was not mentioned in OP question

Answer (score 0):

you need not read localStorage.getItem twice.you can read it into a variable and use the same

```js
var preferences = localStorage.getItem("preferences");
if (preferences == null) {
    //show set preferences page
  } else {
    //you can use this preferences here
    //do stuff
  }
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Call it once and store it in a variable.

```
var preferences = localStorage.getItem("preferences");
if(preferences==null){
    //....
}
else{
    //....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple!

```
var preferences = localStorage.getItem("preferences");

if(preferences == null) {
    //show set preferences page
} else {

    //do stuff with preferences
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative, you could assign preferences within the if statement itself and do the following:

```
if ((preferences = localStorage.getItem("preferences"))) {
    // use preferences here
}
else {
    // set preferences here
}
```

I generally take this approach when its something only I'll be working on, assigning within a condition can confuse some people when debugging.