# How to iterate existing FormControl validators

Tags: angular, validation, angular-validation

I'm trying to do custom validation and I need to add new validators during runtime. This can be accomplished using

```
control.setValidators([control.validator, newValidator.toValidatorFn])
```

where control is instance of AbstractControl.

OK, so far all fine and dandy. However, I would like to check if the validator I'm adding has been already added. I also would like to later locate the validator I added to manipulate it further.

So the question is: how can I iterate through the validators that are attached to certain AbstractControl instance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get validators present in FormGroup/FormControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43838108/get-validators-present-in-formgroup-formcontrol)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible from what it looks like to me.

Internally, `setValidators` is adding the validators (which are *functions*) to a public property on the `AbstractControl` class named `validator`.

Inspecting the `validator` property (with something like `console.log(control.validator)`) will basically show you the whole validation function that will be run for the control.

You can look and the [implementation here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/d0e72a8f8f776c5f92506a6fa60d9cf5b12b61bc/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L213) if you are interested.