# How to get list of form fields which have "required" validation applied to it?

Tags: angular

I want to get a list of form field that has "required" validation applied to it.

So far, I have come with this -
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-forms-yai41z?file=src/app/formreactive/formreactive.component.ts

Here, I am finding which are valid/invalid form fields but I am unable to get its validators. Is there any way to get validators for each field?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43838108/get-validators-present-in-formgroup-formcontrol help?

Comment: Yes, it does help. Thanks!