# Embed Youtube Videos Mute on / off button

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, embed

I want to have a mute button for my site, so when it's pressed it will unmute / mute the audio playing from the background video.
The js I have rn is this. Is there any way I can implement a button with this code?

`enter code here

```html
var videos = [
'D1sZ_vwqwcE',
'BC_Ya4cY8RQ',
'HPc8QMycGno',
'JDglMK9sgIQ',
'hgKDu5pp_fU',
'oKMNj8v2gKE',
'TfnRTifSWh0',
'xO3aB5C3dpQ',
'v5hepekcHkk',
'4kjpZ_sPxzc',
];

var index=Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
var html='<div class="video-background"><div class="video-foreground"><iframe frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' +videos[index] + '?controls=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;&mute=1" allow="autoplay""></iframe></div></div>';
document.write(html);
```

site for reference: https://enph.la

Comment: Use [YouTube Iframe Player API instead](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) - see [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Bvance/8bzxp9c2/) - credits: [Custom mute/unmute button Youtube API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45807269/12511801)

Answer (score 2):

I deserve no credit for this answer, but wanted to point out that the described issue actually got solved in [Custom mute/unmute button Youtube API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45807269/custom-mute-unmute-button-youtube-api) quite well using the YouTube API as it can be seen in this [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Bvance/8bzxp9c2/) from [Marco Aurelio Fernandez Reyes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12511801/marco-aurelio-fernandez-reyes)
(somehow it just works on jsfiddle, but not on stackoverflow...):

```js
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('youtube-video', {
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}

function onPlayerReady() {
  console.log("hey Im ready");
  //do whatever you want here. Like, player.playVideo();

}

function onPlayerStateChange() {
  console.log("my state changed");
}

document.getElementById("mute").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  console.log(player);

  if (player.isMuted()) {
    player.unMute();
  } else {
    player.mute();
  }
});
```

```css
#mute {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<iframe id="youtube-video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1&
    autoplay=1
    &disablekb=1
    &enablejsapi=1
    &loop=1
    &controls=0
    &mute=0" frameborder="0" enablejsapi="1" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<div id="mute">
</div>
<p>
Press red square to mute/unmute
</p>
```

Since a comment easily be overlooked, I just wanted to point out the working solution.