# Is there a better way to write this ternary expression in JSX?

Tags: reactjs

Is there a better way to write this ternary expression in this snippet of JSX?

```
<Form ... error={this.props.errorMessage ? true : false}>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can shorten it slightly by:

```
<Form ... error={!!this.props.errorMessage}>
```

`!!` will turn a value into `true` or `false` depending on whether that value is truthy or falsy.

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty new to JS. Can you tell me if this is widely used or is it something that would leave most people confused.

Comment: In my experience, `!!` is usually not JS 101 and most JS devs come across it by chance, so it depends -- if you're on a team where most are seasoned JS developers, they will have seen this syntax before. If members of the team are new to JS and have experience with other programming languages (especially static ones), I would say leaving it the way you originally had it is clearer.

Answer (score 3):

You can just [double negate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467475/double-negation-in-javascript-what-is-the-purpose) errorMessage prop:

```
<Form ... error={!!this.props.errorMessage}>
```