# handle undefined boolean with ternary operator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
function myFunc(trueOrFalse) {
   return trueOrFalse ? true : false
}
```

above function can be written as `myFunc(trueOrFalse) => trueOrFalse` but what if trueOrFalse is not present? that's why I wrote the first function explicitly return true or false in boolean.

Comment: Why not just get rid of `myFunc` altogether since it seems to be replicating the functionality of the built in `Boolean` function?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `undefined` is `falsy`. when `trueOrFalse` is not present what should be expected response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function arguments without assign are `undefined` which is a `falsy` value. So you can write:

```
function myFunc(trueOrFalse) {
   return trueOrFalse
}
```

Calling `myFunc()` will return `undefined` which is `falsy`. Just Beware that `falsy` is not equals to `false`:

```
if(false) {
    // it will not be executed
}

if(undefined){
    // it will not be executed
}

// but:
false == undefined // false
```

So depending your needs you'd want transform this to `false`, one approach could be using [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters):

```
function myFunc(trueOrFalse = false) {
   return trueOrFalse
}
```

calling `myFunc()` now will return `false`, for example.

Comment: default argument is great, is this es2016 only?

Comment: yes, it is. you can check browser compatibility [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters).

Answer (score 2):

You can double negate that object.

Basically, it's used to convert a `truthy` - `falsy` value to a boolean. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467475/double-negation-in-javascript-what-is-the-purpose)

```js
var myFunc = (trueOrFalse)=> !!trueOrFalse;

console.log(myFunc());
console.log(myFunc('hello'));
console.log(myFunc(true));
console.log(myFunc(false));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: handly, it is like saying it will always be true or false correct?

Comment: @SharonChai yes!

Answer (score 0):

with EcmaScript6 you can set in the function parameters a default
such as

```
function myFunc(trueOrFalse = false){
   return trueOrFalse ? true : false;
}
```

**ECMASCRIPT6 and IE**
Not all aspects of EcmaScript6 are supported by IE 11 or lower, this means you will come into an issue if you set defaults in your function params