# Check if variable is undefined with *ngIf

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I have the following on an Angular 7 application:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(post$ | async) as post; else loader">
  <div *ngIf="post; else empty">
    Post content
  </div>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #empty>
  Post not found
</ng-template>
<ng-template #loader>
  Loading post
</ng-template>
```

This works fine when post is defined ...

However when `post` is undefined the "Post not Found" does not show ...

... I just see the Loading message which does not disappears.

What am I missing?

**Update**

post$ is defined as follows in the component:

**Note:** post$ is not an array. See **envelope.result[0]** in the code.

```
export class PostDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() postId: number;

  post$: Observable<PostDetailModel>;

  constructor(private postService: PostService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.post$ = this.getPost();

  }

  getPost(): Observable<PostDetailModel> {

    return this.postService.getByPostId(this.postId).pipe(

      map((envelope: Envelope<GetByPostIdResponse>) => envelope.result[0]),

      map((response: GetByPostIdResponse) => {

        return response == null ? null : {
          id: response.id,
          title: response.title
          // other properties
        };

      }));

  }
```

Comment: Probably because `post$` would then also not defined which results in an exception. Check your browser's console, are there error messages?

Comment: The observable is defined ...

Comment: Wait, I see. `post` is evaluated as truthy/falsy already in the initial `ng-container`. If `post` resolves to `undefined` then the `ng-template #loader` will display. That makes and I do not see a way for your logic to ever display `ng-template #empty`.

Comment: So how can I check, after loading, if job is defined so I display the Not Found message? This is why I have 2 ngIf

Comment: I would return something other than `undefined` or use `map` to assign something other than `undefined` in the event that the post does not exist on the server.

Comment: @MiguelMoura is post$ an array?

Comment: @Aragorn No, post$ has only one element. Check the update of my question where I show how I am getting the post$

Answer (score 3):

`post` is evaluated as truthy/falsy already in the initial `ng-container`. If `post` resolves to `undefined` then the `ng-template #loader` will display. Your current logic will never display `ng-template #empty`. I would recommend you use `map` to change the returned value if it is `undefined` and then check that in your subsequent `*ngIf`.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xqt3jb)

**component**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  post$: Observable<any>;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.post$ = of(undefined).pipe(
      delay(2000),
      map(_ => typeof _ === 'undefined' ? 'NotFound' : _)
    );
  }
}
```

**template**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(post$ | async) as post; else loader">
  <div *ngIf="post !== 'NotFound'; else empty">
    Post content
  </div>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #empty>
  Post not found
</ng-template>
<ng-template #loader>
  Loading post
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `!!` to check for valid values. You can see explanation of `!!`  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10467486/9386929)

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(post$ | async) as post; else loader">
      <div *ngIf="!!post; else empty">
        Post content
      </div>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #empty>
      Post not found
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #loader>
      Loading post
    </ng-template>
```

Comment: It did not work ... The loader still does not disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I think its always undefined. Undefined while its waiting, and also undefined or maybe null when it returns in that state. I think the best way to to be more explicit about whats going on:

ts

```
loading = false;
post;

getPost() {
   this.loading = true;
   this.postService.getPost().subscribe(post => {
      this.loading = false;
      this.post = post;
   });
}
```

html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!loading; else loader">
  <div *ngIf="post; else empty">
    Post content
  </div>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #empty>
  Post not found
</ng-template>
<ng-template #loader>
  Loading post
</ng-template>
```

this way you aren't trying to infer the state of the post from which kind of falsey it might be