# How to move all elements that are zero to the end of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Write a function that takes an array of values and moves all elements that are zero to the end of the array, otherwise preserving the order of the array. The zero elements must also maintain the order in which they occurred.

Zero elements are defined by either 0 or "0". Some tests may include elements that are not number literals.

NOT allowed to use any temporary arrays or objects. Also not allowed to use any Array.prototype or Object.prototype methods.So no array.push or splice() is allowed.

I tried this:

```
function removeZeros(nums) {

   for(let i = nums.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--){
    if(nums[i] === 0){
      nums.splice(i, 1);
      nums.push(0);
    }
   }
   return nums;
}
```

#### input:

```
[7, 2, 3, 0, 4, 6, 0, 0, 13, 0, 78, 0, 0, 19, 14]
```

#### Expected:

```
[7, 2, 3, 4, 6, 13, 78, 19, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

#### Actual:

```
[7, 2, 3, 4, 6, 13, 78, 19, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Result is coming as correct but I need to do it without array.push() or array.splice()

Answer (score 3):

- Take length of original array
- Filter nonZero values from original array
- add zeros at the end as per difference in length of filtered array and original array

```js
function removeZeros(nums) {
   let originalLen = nums.length
   let nonZero = nums.filter(Boolean)
   return [...nonZero,...new Array(originalLen-nonZero.length).fill(0)]
}

console.log(removeZeros([7, 2, 3, 0, 4, 6, 0, 0, 13, 0, 78, 0, 0, 19, 14]))
```

---

> Also not allowed to use any Array.prototype or Object.prototype
>   methods

```js
function removeZeros(nums) {
   let originalLen = nums.length
   let final = []
   for(let i=0;i<nums.length; i++){
    if(nums[i]) final = [...final, nums[i]]
   }
   let lenDiff = originalLen-final.length
   while(lenDiff){
    final = [...final,0]
    lenDiff--
   }
   return final
}

console.log(removeZeros([7, 2, 3, 0, 4, 6, 0, 0, 13, 0, 78, 0, 0, 19, 14]))
```

Comment: But you are using filter function which is one of the methods of  Array.prototype or Object.prototype which is not allowed here.@Code Maniac

Comment: Array.push() in the updated code is also not allowed here.

Comment: @ArjunKumar so much of restrictions, anyways you can use `spread syntax, concat whichever` you like

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```js
const arr = [7, 2, 3, 0, 4, 6, 0, 0, 13, 0, 78, 0, 0, 19, 14]

arr.sort((a, b) => (a === 0) - (b === 0))

console.log(arr)
```

Subtracting booleans returns a 1, -1 or 0.

```
true - false === 1
false - true === -1
true - true === 0
```

If `a` is 0 and `b` isn't, 1 will be returned and `a` will be moved to the end of the array. If both `a` and `b` are zero or non-zero, they aren't moved relative to each other.

---

The simplest way to move certain items to one end is to collect the items to 2 separate arrays based on the condition and concatenate them in the end.

```js
const arr = [7, 2, 3, 0, 4, 6, 0, 0, 13, 0, 78, 0, 0, 19, 14],
      zeros = [],
      nonZeros = []

for (const n of arr) {
  if (n === 0)
    zeros.push(n)
  else
    nonZeros.push(n)
}

const output = nonZeros.concat(zeros);
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop, iterate through the array, and use a simple conditional to check zeroes.

```
var arr = [7, 2, 3, 0, 4, 6, 0, 0, 13, 0, 78, 0, 0, 19, 14];
var prev_zero_index = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] != 0 && arr[i - 1] == 0) {
    prev_zero_index++;
    arr[prev_zero_index] = arr[i];
    arr[i] = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Without using array.push & array.splice only I have written the algorithm to move zeroes to the end of the array. I did not get your comment about array values order is changed?

Answer (score 0):

```
function pushZeros(arr) {
  let count = 0; 
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i] !== 0) arr[count++] = arr[i]; 
  }
  while (count < arr.length) arr[count++] = 0;

  return arr;
}
```

Basically I am looping through all elements of array, picking nonzero element as I loop and storing it from 0th position in same array.  After I am done looping, count will be equal to total nonzero elements in array.  Rest all can be then initialized to zero.

Comment: syntax error unmatched right curly brace after the `for`.

Comment: While the code may answer the question, explaining the main points improves the quality of the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do something like this:

```js
let data = [7, 2, 3, 0, 4, 6, 0, 0, 13, 0, 78, 0, 0, 19, 14]

let result = data.sort((a,b) => !!b-!!a)

console.log(result)
```

Where you would sort on the boolean value of each of the array entries.  We cast to boolean via the [double negation operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467475/double-negation-in-javascript-what-is-the-purpose/10467486). Since `!!0` would be false and every other number would be true and we sort in a descending order (hence `b-a` and not `a-b`) we get the desired result.

Please note that `Array.sort` mutates the current array and if you want to create a new one simply use `Array.slice` like this:

```js
let data = [7, 2, 3, 0, 4, 6, 0, 0, 13, 0, 78, 0, 0, 19, 14]

let sortZeroesLast = arr => arr.slice().sort((a,b) => !!b-!!a)

console.log(data) // <-- original array
console.log(sortZeroesLast(data))  // <-- new sorted array
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `sort()` to sort the list based on its equality to `0`, like this!

```
let numbers = [7, 2, 3, 0, 4, 6, 0, 0, 13, 0, 78, 0, 0, 19, 14];

numbers.sort((a, b) => {
  if (b === 0) return -1;
  return 1;
});

console.log(numbers); //[7, 2, 3, 4, 6, 13, 78, 19, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```