# useState in useEffect does not update state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to React Hooks and using react 16.13.1.

I'm going to implement `Auth` component which enables to handle logging in.

But it does not seem update the state `currentUser` properly, even though `setCurrentUser` is called with response Object.

What is wrong with this code?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { checkLoggedIn } from "utils/Api";

export const Auth = (props) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  console.log(currentUser);

  useEffect(() => {
    const f = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      console.log(isLoading);
      const res = await checkLoggedIn();
      if (!!res) { // ==> true
        setCurrentUser(res);
        console.log(currentUser); // ==> null!
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
    };
    f();
  });

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>loading</div>;
  }

  console.log(currentUser); // ==> null!
  return !!currentUser ? (
    <Route children={props.children} />
  ) : (
    <Redirect to={"/login"} />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 14):

`setCurrentUser` updates the state asynchronously, so you can't use `currentUser` immediately afterwards.

However, you can use another `useEffect` to know when the state was changed:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // currentUser changed
}, [currentUser])
```

I also noticed that you are not passing an empty array to the `useEffect` you already have, so it will trigger everytime the component is updated. If you need to execute your `useEffect` only once you have to pass an empty array as a second argument, like this:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const f = async () => {
      // ...
    };
    f();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 4):

It could be a problem with calling setter of state (setCurrentUser) because of asynchronous nature of setting state in React. I haven't found any clear answer is it async as setState or sync when I was working with React. In my opinion, the best solution in such complicated cases just to use classes. It will give you a lot of lifecycle methods that cannot be reproduced with hooks and will be more appropriate in auth component.
React Hooks is not a replacement of classes in all situations and just a tool that allow you to not break existing code while you need just to do simple improvements.

Comment: Also, as for me, code with useEffect looks not so readable as with componentDidUpdate and componentWillReceiveProps

Answer (score 4):

As @germanescobar already answered `setCurrentUser` updates state asynchronously. Hence you need to `useEffect` with dependency list containing only `currentUser` to get the latest state value.

However, for your use case you're only interested in whether the `currentUser` is truthy and based on that you want to redirect the user to required page. So you don't need another `useEffect` as you are not performing any other side-effect based on the `currentUser`.

In real-world scenario you want to show the loading/splash screen until you're able to decide whether the user is authenticated or not. So you should change the initial value of `isLoading` to `true` and change the state to `false` once your async task is done. I'll suggest you to rename the state name to something like:

`const [shouldCheckLogin, setShouldCheckLogin] = useState(true)`.

Lastly, `!!null` is `false` whereas `!!{}` is `true`. For values which are `object` it's completely fine to initialize them with `null`.

```js
console.log(!!null)
console.log(!!{})
```

Comment: Here is a great article by Dan Abramov introducing hooks: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/making-sense-of-react-hooks-fdbde8803889

Comment: `!!` what is the use of this operator? any useful link would be appreciated.

Comment: Generally this is called double negation operator. It'll just perform(negate) `!` twice. The second time it performs the negation on the result of first one. Here is a SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467475/double-negation-in-javascript-what-is-the-purpose

Comment: `!! expr` is the shorthand for `Boolean(expr)`

Answer (score 3):

Thank you @germanescobar and @Vadim for teaching me many things!

And I noticed now that the argument of `useState` has something to do with this problem.

changing

```
const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
```

into

```
const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState({});
```

seems to have solved the not-updating problem (I don't know the reason though).

Comment: It's a good practice to have initial state as the same type of what you will assign later to it. Hard to say that this is really solves the problem. Better to stick with @germanescobar solution or to use classes, I think

Comment: I used germanescobar's solution too, but I had to change initial state to {} too.