# Issue of usestate updated value not updated inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, expo

In below simple app I am retrieving value of coordinate through expo-location and storing in a usestate, but some how console value for both latitude and longitude return undefined.Any help would be highly appreciated. I want to retrieve both coordinate value on loading this component and in later state use them to set location in map.

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import MapView, { Callout, Marker, PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from 'react-native-maps';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
```

export default function App() {

```
  const [location, setLocation] = useState();
  const [address, setAddress] = useState();
  const [latitude, setLatitude] = useState();
  const [longitude, setLongitude] = useState();
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);



  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
        return;
      }
     
    
    })();
    Location.installWebGeolocationPolyfill();
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(pos =>{
      setLongitude(pos.coords.longitude);
       setLatitude(pos.coords.latitude);     
       console.log("latitude: ", latitude);
       console.log("longitude: ", longitude);
       });
   // 
  }, []);
```

Comment: It won't update until next render. below is an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64191994/22253691

Answer (score 1):

The thing is `setState` is asynchronous. When you call these functions, React does not immediately update the state.
If you want you can use another `useEffect` to log the updated values whenever the state changes:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("latitude: ", latitude);
}, [latitude]);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("longitude: ", longitude);
}, [longitude]);
```

Answer (score 0):

because react does not immediately update the state you can log the new values:

```
console.log("latitude: ", pos.coords.longitude);
console.log("longitude: ", pos.coords.latitude);
```

now it's the same values like the states.

Answer (score 0):

This is **not an issue**. Both `latitude` & `longitude` are already updated, you cannot see immediately if you put console.log() right after updating state.

**Example**

Look at the code below, and see now long it takes  for better understanding.

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
        return;
      }
    })();

    Location.installWebGeolocationPolyfill();
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pos) => {
      setLongitude(pos.coords.longitude);
      setLatitude(pos.coords.latitude);
      console.log('1: ', latitude);
      console.log('2: ', longitude);
    });
    console.log('11: ', latitude);
    console.log('22: ', longitude);
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      {console.log('33: ', latitude)}
      {console.log('33: ', longitude)}
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>latitude: {latitude}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>longitude: {longitude}</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
```

**No need to useEffect again**.