# Is it redundant using !! boolean structure when the value is either true or false?

Tags: javascript, boolean, negation

There are other questions about !! (double negation) already ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467475/double-negation-in-javascript-what-is-the-purpose), [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)), and these questions answer my confusion about this. But what I want to know with this question is more specific... Here it is my case.

I have eslint set on my codebase, and I fixed all fixable errors recently.

One of these fixes including the double exclamation sign negation.

One example before the fix and after:

```js
// BEFORE eslint fix:
import { IS_DEV } from "./config/clientUrl";
const sandboxMode = IS_DEV ? true : false;
```

```js
// AFTER eslint fix:
import { IS_DEV } from "./config/clientUrl";
const sandboxMode = !!IS_DEV;
```

The fix was correct in detect that it was redundant since is IS_DEV is already a boolean here. So I know the value is either true or false.

So, is there any difference using double negation like this:

```js
const sandboxMode = !!IS_DEV;
```

and using simply without it:

```js
const sandboxMode = IS_DEV;
```

This wouldn't be another redundancy in this case?

Comment: I think it's completely harmless and it makes the code readable: an experienced JavaScript programmer would recognize  that you're creating a `true` or `false` value.

Comment: It is redundant if you know `IS_DEV` is Boolean. But then so of course is your original. Eslint doesn't know the type though, and for a value of unknown type your "fixed" version is much more idiomatic than the original ternary.

Answer (score 1):

A few points to my answer:

- If you know for sure that IS_DEV will be either `true` or `false` (a boolean) and NEVER anything else, you can just use this: `const sandboxMode = IS_DEV`
- If it's possible that IS_DEV is going to not be set (thus being `undefined`), you should use `const sandboxMode = !!IS_DEV` which will force `sandboxMode` to be a boolean
- But it also depends on how `sandboxMode` is being consumed!